# Problem while importing spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am importing spring boot project after generating the zip file from spring.start.io -
[spring.start.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToOw7.png)

Complete project is not getting imported .It is giving errors in pom.xml like
Failure to transfer com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.10.4 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.10.4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.10.4/jackson-bom-2.10.4.pom. Error code 501, HTTPS Required

It is imported as-
[How it is imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHzUS.png)

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add -U as argument of your mvn command to force the update of depedencies cached in your repository ? ex :

```
mvn -U clean install
```

You also have a warning about https that is required by maven central so set https in sour maven settings.xml

like :

```
<settings>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>internal-repository</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Manager running on https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
</settings>
```

You also have an error about https as http is no longer supported on maven repository. You have to set http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/ if you really have no choice to use insecure http. It's well documented :

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required

Best regards.

Comment: But now maven dependencies are not getting downloaded @GweltazNiquel

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: I am new to this .What does that  mean?@GweltazNiquel

Comment: If you are working in a firm : most of them put a proxy on their Internet access. ask your collegues if there is one. If so, you'll have to configure your proxy access in your maven settings.xml so that it could download depedencies through it.

Comment: No I am not behind a proxy.

Comment: You had an error saying that "https were required". Make sure you set https and not http in url tag of your repo and if you don't have another error.